# multiple button click event handler

Tags: jquery, backbone.js

I have the following in my html template

```
<div id="add">
    <fieldset>
    </fieldset>
    <input type="button"  id="cancel" value="AddCancel"/>
</div>
<div id="update">
    <fieldset>
    </fieldset>
    <input type="button" id="cancel" value="UpdateCancel"/>
</div>
```

The events are wired up with backbone for the buttons. What I am running into is that i have to wire up `AddCancel` event and `UpdateCancel` event and so on.

Instead of wiring up each cancel button event, is there a way i could have 1 `cancel` button event and handler which could identify which div the cancel button that was clicked belongs to?

Comment: IDs must be unique, your HTML is invalid. Use class instead. And to answer your question: "Yes, we can!"

Comment: Why not just have separate events for `AddCancel` and `UpdateCancel` and then just invoke a reusable "Cancel" function allowing you to reuse the same logic for both?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have just one event. first make sure your html is correct, it cannot have two buttons with the same ID. use classes instead

```
<div id="add">
    <fieldset>
    </fieldset>
    <input type="button"  class="cancelbtn" id="btn1" value="AddCancel"/>
</div>
<div id="update">
    <fieldset>
    </fieldset>
    <input type="button" class="cancelbtn" id="btn2" value="UpdateCancel"/>
</div>
```

Next use this code in jquery

```
$(".cancelbtn").on("click", function(e){
    var buttonType = $(this).attr("value")
    if(buttonType == "AddCancel"){
        //AddCancel Button Clicked
    }else{
        //UpdateCancel Button Clicked
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this :

```
var YourView ...
    events: {
        'click .cancel': 'cancel'
    },

    cancel: function(event) {
        var parent = event.currentTarget.parent(); // gets the parent of the clicked button
        ...
    }
    ...
```

and the html :

```
<div id="add">
    <fieldset>
    </fieldset>
    <input type="button" class="cancel" value="AddCancel"/>
</div>
<div id="update">
    <fieldset>
    </fieldset>
    <input type="button" class="cancel" value="UpdateCancel"/>
</div>
```