# How to load external files into a div using either js or jQ

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've got some html content in a div, and the content runs to very nearly 12,000 lines.  I've sub-divided the content into a series of smaller divs, but having that many lines for display on a single page is unwieldy.  What I'd like to do is put each smaller div into an external file--probably html, because I need to use a lot of unicode to get the typography to display properly--and load each external file into the div from a menu item (button or simple link). I've done this using php, but after a few hours of searching stackoverflow I'm convinced it can be done using js or jQuery and I'd much prefer to go that route.  However, I can't get any of the solutions offered on stackoverflow to work for me.  To be clear, I do not want something with the content contained on the same page as the script.  I'm trying to reduce the size of the main page by dividing it into multiple pages.  Here's the php I wrote a few years ago to accomplish the same feat, in case that helps anyone to envision what I'm trying to do.

```
<?php

if ( $_GET['page'] == 'Page1') {
$filename = 'sub/' . 'Page1.html';
include $filename;
} elseif ( $_GET['page'] == 'Page2') {
$filename = 'sub/' . 'Page2.html';
include $filename;
} elseif ( $_GET['page'] == 'Page3') {
$filename = 'sub/' . 'Page3.html';
include $filename;
} elseif ( $_GET['page'] == 'Page4') {
$filename = 'sub/' . 'Page4.html';
include $filename;
} elseif ( $_GET['page'] == 'Page5') {
$filename = 'sub/' . 'Page5.html';
include $filename;
}
else {

echo "Here sits the main page content"
?>
```

It seems like various forms of this question were asked fairly often in 2012, so I guess I'm behind the times, but I'm relatively new to both javascript and jQuery.  And my lack of knowledge has made it impossible for me to implement any of the few "looks like this should work" solutions to similar questions I've found here.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: With jQuery you would use the `.load()` function. http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: You could have everything in one file and load one portion of it with something like `$( "#result" ).load( "ajax/test.html #container" );`

Comment: Thanks Jay.  Your directions look likely to lead me to a solution.

Comment: Thanks putvande, but I want to avoid having everything in just one file.  The resulting file is simply too large.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With help from those who offered me answers here I was led to a StackOverflow page here -- [multiple button click event handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22206144/multiple-button-click-event-handler) -- that enabled me to develop the answer I needed.  For the benefit of others who might what to add multiple html pages to a single div on a master page by way of button clicks, here some of the jQuery code I used:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".page1").click(function(){
    $("#poem").load("pages/page1.html",function(responseTxt,statusTxt,xhr){
      if(statusTxt=="success")
        alert("External content loaded successfully!");
      if(statusTxt=="error")
        alert("Error: "+xhr.status+": "+xhr.statusText);
    });
  });

  $(".page2").click(function(){
      $("#poem").load("pages/page2.html",function(responseTxt,statusTxt,xhr){
        if(statusTxt=="success")
          alert("External content loaded successfully!");
        if(statusTxt=="error")
          alert("Error: "+xhr.status+": "+xhr.statusText);
      });
    });

$(".page3").click(function(){
 $("#poem").load("books/page3.html",function(responseTxt,statusTxt,xhr){
  if(statusTxt=="success")
    alert("External content loaded successfully!");
  if(statusTxt=="error")
    alert("Error: "+xhr.status+": "+xhr.statusText);
  });
 });
});
</script>
```

and the buttons look like this:

```
<input type="button" class="book1" value="Book I" />
<input type="button" class="book2" value="Book II" />
<input type="button"  class="book3" value="Book III"/>
```

I'm leaving the success and failure alerts in for now, until I finish all the pages and know for sure that everything loads smoothly.  The script is correct, but it's still possible I could mistype or mislabel something as I built.

Thanks again to PugsOverDrugs and Jay Blanchard.

Answer (score 0):

Hook the change up to a click event using jQuery's AJAX ( this thing is amazing. ).

EX:

```
$( document ).on( 'click', '#MyButton', function()
{
     $.ajax({                                                 
          url: 'myPHPFILe.php',    
          data: 
            {
                Page: $( #MyButton ).prop( id ); //Assuming ID is page1, page2, etc.. 
            },

          success: function( result ) 
          {
              $( '#MyDiv' ).html( result ); //This will strip the html inside of your div and replace it with the HTML generated by the url you linked to.
          }
        });
});
```

NOTE: Make sure to change your jQuery callouts, and it's a good idea to set things like the div id to a var for repeated use.

To read more on the different methods and parameters for AJAX just hit up google, people have great examples and documentation. This WILL work ( if used properly ) :)

Comment: Thanks PugsOverDrugs.  This will probably work for me.  I don't yet have enough reputation to be able to vote your answer up.  I tried, and was told I don't.  Otherwise I would.  I hope I'll soon be able to check it as the answer to my problem, though.